# Load content From Include File within plugin

Tags: include

The title isn't the best, so feel free to change it to make
it more clear...

Problem:

I am trying to load up a page from within a plugin and replace anything that WP puts out. Have it set so if they are on the front page of the site, it will display a PHP page within my plugin:

```
if(is_front_page()){

    $full_path = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( FILE),"",plugin_basename(FILE));

    $url = $full_path . "/PLUGINNAME/file.php";

    include($url);

    die();
}
```

But thats not outputting the file. Even when I put the FULL path to the PHP file, it wont display it, or anything. It will only render up this point, in the source code:

```
 <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.3.1" />
```

Then after that, its nothing.

I have never been able to get include to work, I really don't want to use an iFrame solution.

Thoughts? :)

Thanks!

- Dylan

**UPDATE**

So I used get_file_contents and the hook template_redirect to achieve this.

Going to do some testing on the live server to see whats up! :)

Comment: doing echo file_get_contents("$url", true); works, but the CSS has to be loaded with full paths, is there any solution to fully display a page like include would?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution might be to do it along the lines of

```
/* In your main plugin file */
if ( ! defined( 'YOUR_PLUGIN_ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'YOUR_PLUGIN_ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
}

/* In any file of the plugin */
if( is_front_page() ) {
    /* adjust path if file.php is in a subfolder */
    require_once ( YOUR_PLUGIN_ABSPATH . '/file.php' );
}
```

If you still have to deal with full paths, they're in your *file.php*.

**Additional Option**

Also, it might not be the best idea to use a conditional tag (`if( is_front_page() )`). Alternatively, you could have the plugin generate a shortcode, which outputs the desired markup.

This would have two benefits: For one, it is easily placed and moved within your (front-)page. For another, you can use it anywhere you like, and that without altering code.

```
/* In your main plugin file */
if ( ! defined( 'YOUR_PLUGIN_ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'YOUR_PLUGIN_ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
}

/* In any file of the plugin */
function your_include( $atts ) {
    /* "path" is a shortcode attribute, you can use it to include several files */
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'path' => 'file.php'
        ),
        $atts ) );

    require_once ( YOUR_PLUGIN_ABSPATH . '/' . $path );

    /**
    * file.php should be adjusted to save whatever you were echoing in before
    * in a variable (in this example $output), which is returned
    * by the shortcode function
    */

    return $output
}
add_shortcode( 'your-include', 'your_include' );
```